# How to hatch turtles constantly in a defined area once the preceding turtle leave?

Tags: netlogo

I am the novice netlogo user. Recently, I am trying to develop a model to simulate the air traffic flow under the terminal area. Now I am able to vector a single aircraft to land, and I want to constantly vector more aircraft to enter the terminal area. My idea is to define an area (named spawnpool) around the entry point as the picture shown. When the preceding aircraft left the area, I hatch a new aircraft to enter. If there is any aircraft in the "spawnpool", no more aircraft should be hatched.

[image: Displayed PNG in OP]

But I am not sure how to fulfill this idea properly. As the picture shown after the first aircraft leave the area of "spawnpool". Tons of aircraft appears, I am not sure this mistake is due to insufficient proficiency or unsuitable idea for this purpose. Sincerely looking for some insights for this issue.

```
to setup-spawnpool
  ask patches
  [set spawnpool? (pxcor > -8.4  and pxcor < -5.4 and pycor < 5.8 and pycor > 
3.8 )  ]
end


to new-aircraft-approaching0
 ask aircrafts [
    while [spawnpool? = false ]
 [hatch-aircrafts 1
      [ set color black 
        set size 0.7
        setxy -7.4 4.8
        route-check-02]]]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, your problem is that you have many patches each with spawnpool? set to true. Your `while` statement is then asking each aircraft to check the `patch` it happens to be sitting on whether that patch has spawnpool set to true. So they continually hatch new aircraft. What you really want to do is create a new aircraft when none of the spawnpool? patches have an aircraft on them. This involves many changes:

1. `sprout` or `create` rather than `hatch` an aircraft so that it doesn't inherit its parent's attributes
2. you should not be using `while` because `while` operates continuously without advancing the clock
3. you need to ask all the patches whether there is an aircraft one them

I can't test this as I would need to create breeds etc to make the model run. But you want something like:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  setup-spawnpool
  ...
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ...
  new-aircraft-approaching0
  ...
  tick
end

to setup-spawnpool
  ask patches
  [set spawnpool? (pxcor > -8.4  and pxcor < -5.4 and pycor < 5.8 and pycor > 3.8 )
  ]
end

to new-aircraft-approaching0
  let aircraft-source patches with [ spawnpool? ]
  if not any? aircrafts-on aircraft-source
  [ ask one-of aircraft-source
    [ sprout-aircrafts 1
      [ set color black 
        set size 0.7
        setxy -7.4 4.8
        route-check-02]
       ]
     ]
   ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks! the problem was well solved. Actually, I also managed to come up another way. I set a variable for aircraft as 1000, as the aircraft forwad 3 per ticks, the variable 1000 also decreases gradually. And when the variable is in the interval between 2 and 4, it hatch a new aircraft. Since there is definitely a only timing of which the variable is 3. So each of the aircraft can only hatch an aircraft once. However, this method reduce the speed of the simulation significantly. It is still better to use the idea you provided.